# ошибка кучи, программа падает после компиляции

Tags: c

помогите пожалуйста разобраться в коде. Я когда компилирую и выбираю один из видом сортировки, компилятор мне сортирует массив, но потом программа ломается и не работает.

```
include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "locale.h"

void Print(int B[], int* n);
void swap(int B[], int i)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = B[i];
    B[i] = B[i - 1];
    B[i - 1] = tmp;
}
void randArray(int B[], int* n, int* a, int* b)
{
    int i;
        printf("Введите размер массива\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &*n);
        printf("Введите наименьший элемент в массиве\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &*a);
        printf("Введите наибольший элемент в массиве\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &*b);
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        B[i] = rand() % (*b - *a) + *a;
    Print(B, n);
}
void specArray(int B[], int* n)
{
    int i;
        printf("Введите размер массива\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &*n);
    printf("Введите элементы массива\n");
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &B[i]);
    Print(B, n);
}
void Print(int B[], int* n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void DibBubbleSort(int B[], int *n)
{
    int leftmark = 1;
    int rightmark = n - 1;
    while (leftmark <= rightmark)
    {
        for (int i = rightmark; i >= leftmark; i--)
            if (B[i - 1] > B[i]) swap(B, i);
        leftmark++;

        for (int i = leftmark; i <= rightmark; i++)
            if (B[i - 1] > B[i]) swap(B, i);
        rightmark--;

    }
}
void InsertSort(int B[], int* n)
{
    int i, j, pos;
    for (i = 1; i < *n; i++)
    {
        j = B[i];
        pos = i - 1;
        while ((pos >= 0) && (B[pos] > j))
        {
            B[pos + 1] = B[pos];
            pos = pos - 1;
        }
        B[pos + 1] = j;
    }
}
void Merge(int B[], int left, int right)
{
    int mid, pos1, pos2, pos3, i, *A, n=&n;
    A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    mid = (left + right) / 2;
    {
        pos1 = left;
        pos2 = mid + 1;
        pos3 = 1;
    }
    while ((pos1 <= mid) && (pos2 <= right))
    {
        if (B[pos1] < B[pos2])
        {
            A[pos3] = B[pos1];
        pos1++;
        }
        else
        {
            A[pos3] = B[pos2];
            pos2++;
        }
        pos3++;
    }
    while (pos2 <= right)
    {
        A[pos3] = B[pos2];
        pos2++;
        pos3++;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < pos3 - 1; i++)
        B[left + i - 1] = A[i];
    free(A);
};
void MergeSort(int* B[], int left, int right)
{
        if (left < right)
        {
            MergeSort(B, left, (left + right)/2); //сортировка левой части
            MergeSort(B, (left+right)/2 + 1, right); //сортировка правой части
            Merge(B, left, right); //слияние двух частей
        }
};
void Split(int B[], int left, int right)
{
    int mid, i, j, tmp;
    mid = B[(right + left) / 2];
    i = left;
    j = right;
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (B[i] < mid)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (B[j] > mid)
        {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) 
        {
            tmp = B[i];
            B[i] = B[j];
            B[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        Split(B, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        Split(B, i, right);
}
void QuickSort(int* B[], int* n)
{
    Split(B, 0, *n - 1);
}
void menu()
{
    printf("\nMENU:\n");
    printf("1. Ввод заданного массива\n");
    printf("2. Ввод рандомного массива\n");
    printf("3. Быстрая сортировка\n");
    printf("4. Сортировка двунаправленным пузырьком\n");
    printf("5. Сортировка вставками\n");
    printf("6. Сортировка слиянием\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
}
void main()
{
    int n = &n, a = &a, b = &b;
    int* B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    int t = 10;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    printf("start\n");
    srand(1000);

    while (t != 0)
    {
        menu();
        scanf_s("%d", &t);
        switch (t)
        {
        case 1: {
            specArray(B, &n);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            randArray(B, &n, &a, &b);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            QuickSort(B, &n);
            Print(B, &n);
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            DibBubbleSort(B, &n);
            Print(B, &n);
        }
        case 5: {
            InsertSort(B, &n);
            Print(B, &n);
        }
        case 6: {
            MergeSort(B, 0, &n);
            Print(B, &n);
        }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь

```
int mid, pos1, pos2, pos3, i, *A, n=&n

int n = &n, a = &a, b = &b;
int* B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

грубая ошибка. Целочисленной переменной `n` присваивается её адрес. Этот адрес обрезается до типа `int`. Полная бессмыслица. Ошибок может быть очень много.

сначала спрашивайте размер `scanf` , потом выделяйте память.